# ¿Por qué a veces da violación de segmento (segmentation fault) y a veces no, el mismo código?

Tags: c, hashmap

Estoy trabajando en C con tablas de Hash y ocurre que, el código que estoy corriendo a veces da violación de segmento (segmentation fault) y a veces corre sin problema. No logro comprender por qué.

El código es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define INFINITO 32
#define NODO sizeof(node *)
#define LISTA sizeof(list *)
#define TABLAHASH sizeof(hashTable *)

/* Declaración nodoLista */
struct nodo;

/* Definición tipo nodo */
typedef struct nodo node;

/* Atributos de struct nodo */
struct nodo {
    char *nombre;
    node *siguiente;
};

/* Prototipos de métodos de nodo */

node *crearNodo();

node *copiarNodo(node *buffer, node *elemento);

void imprimirNodo(node *elemento);

/* Declaración lista */
struct lista {
    node *cabeza;
    int  longitud;
};

/* Definición tipo list. */
typedef struct lista list;

/* Prototipos de métodos de lista */
list *crearLista();

void agregarElemento(list *lista, node *elemento);

node *buscarElemento(list *lista, char *nombre);

node *borrarElemento(list *lista, char *nombre);

void imprimirLista(list *lista);

/* Declaración tablaHash */
 struct tablaHash {
    list *cuerpo[26];
    int elementos;
 };

 /* Definición tipo hashTable */
 typedef struct tablaHash hashTable;

 /* Prototipos de métodos de tablaHash */
 hashTable *crearTabla();

 int hash(char *string);

 void agregar(hashTable *tabla, char *string);

 char *buscar(hashTable *tabla, char* string);

 char *eliminar(hashTable *tabla, char* string);

 void imprimirTabla(hashTable *tabla);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    hashTable *prueba0 = crearTabla();
    int i;
    char x = 'A';
    printf("%d\n", (*prueba0).elementos);
    agregar(prueba0, "ID1111");
    imprimirTabla(prueba0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*  La función crearNodo solicita al SO memoria dinámica mediante la   función
 *  malloc para un nodo y lo inicializa si y solo si la memoria es asignada. Si
 *  ocurre un error en la asignación de memoria se provoca la finalización del
 *  programa.
 */
node *crearNodo() {
    node *nuevo = (node *) malloc(NODO);
    if (nuevo == NULL) {
        printf("No hay memoria suficiente para continuar.\n");
        printf("El programa terminará\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*nuevo).nombre = malloc(INFINITO * sizeof(char));
    (*nuevo).siguiente = (node *) NULL;
    return nuevo;
}

/*  La función copiarNodo recibe dos nodos, buffer y elemento, copia los valores
 *  de elemento en buffer y retorna este útlimo.
 */
node *copiarNodo(node *buffer, node *elemento) {
     (*buffer).nombre = strcpy((*buffer).nombre, (*elemento).nombre);
     return buffer;
}

/*  La función imprimirNodo recibe un nodo apuntado por elemento y muestra por
 *  la salida estándar el atributo nombre de elemento.
 */
void imprimirNodo(node *elemento) {
    printf("%s", (*elemento).nombre);
}

/*  La función crearLista solicita al SO memoria dinámica mediante la función
 *  malloc para una listaOrdenada y la inicializa si y solo si la memoria es
 *  asignada. Si ocurre un error en la asignación de memoria se provoca la
 *  finalización del programa.
 */
list *crearLista() {
    list *nueva = (list *) malloc(LISTA);
    if (nueva == NULL) {
        printf("No hay memoria suficiente para continuar.\n");
        printf("El programa terminará\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*nueva).cabeza = NULL;
    (*nueva).longitud = 0;
    return nueva;
}

/*  La función agregarElemento recibe una lista apuntada por lista y un nodo
 *  apuntado por elemento y lo agrega a lista manteniendo un orden. La relación
 *  de orden definida es: 
 *      Sean A, B elementos de la lista, A precede a B si y sólo si A.nombre <=
 *      B.nombre.
 */
void agregarElemento(list *lista, node *elemento) {
    node *nuevo = crearNodo();
    nuevo = copiarNodo(nuevo, elemento);
    if ((*lista).longitud == 0) {
        (*lista).cabeza = nuevo;
        (*lista).longitud++;
    } else {
        node *aux = (*lista).cabeza;
        node *anterior = NULL;
        while (aux != NULL) {
            if (strcmp((*nuevo).nombre,(*aux).nombre) < 0) { //Sitio adecuado.
                if (anterior == NULL) { //Se añade a la cabeza.
                    (*nuevo).siguiente = (*lista).cabeza;
                    (*lista).cabeza = nuevo;
                } else { //Se añade en el medio o al final.
                    (*anterior).siguiente = nuevo;
                    (*nuevo).siguiente = crearNodo();
                    (*nuevo).siguiente = aux;
                }
                (*lista).longitud++;
                aux = NULL;
            } else { //Sitio no adecuado.
                anterior = aux;
                aux = (*aux).siguiente;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*  La función buscarElemento recibe una lista apuntada por lista y un string
 *  apuntado por nombre y busca en la lista al elemento cuyo atributo nombre
 *  coincide con nombre y lo retorna si lo encuentra. Si no lo encuentra retorna
 *  NULL.
 */
node *buscarElemento(list *lista, char *nombre) {
    node *aux = (*lista).cabeza;
    int encontrado = 1;
    while (aux != NULL && encontrado != 0) {
        encontrado = strcmp((*aux).nombre, nombre);
        if (encontrado == 0) {
            return aux;
        } else {
            aux = (*aux).siguiente;
        }
    }
    return aux;
}

/*  La función borrarElemento recibe una lista apuntada por lista y un string
 *  apuntado por nombre. Busca al elemento en la lista cuyo atributo nombre
 *  coincide con nombre y si lo encuentra libera su espacio de memoria con la
 *  función free y lo elimina de la lista. Si no lo encuentra retorna NULL
 */
node *borrarElemento(list *lista, char *nombre) {
    node *aux = (*lista).cabeza;
    node *anterior = NULL;
    int encontrado = 1;
    while (aux != NULL && encontrado != 0) {
        encontrado = strcmp((*aux).nombre, nombre);
        if (encontrado == 0) { //Encontrado.
            if (anterior == NULL) { //Si era la cabeza.
                (*lista).cabeza = (*aux).siguiente;
            } else { //Si no era la cabeza.
                (*anterior).siguiente = (*aux).siguiente;
            }
            (*lista).longitud--;
            free(aux);
            return aux;
        } else { //No encontrado.
            anterior = aux;
            aux = (*aux).siguiente;
      }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*  La función imprimirLista recibe una lista apuntada por lista y muestra por
 *  la salida estándar los nombres de los elementos de la lista separados por
 *  comas (,).
 */
 void imprimirLista(list *lista) {
    if ((*lista).longitud > 0) {
        node *copia = (*lista).cabeza;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < (*lista).longitud) {
            if (i + 1 == (*lista).longitud) {
                printf("%s\n", (*copia).nombre);
            } else {
                printf("%s, ", (*copia).nombre);
            }
            copia = (*copia).siguiente;
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/*  La función crearTabla solicita al SO memoria dinámica mediante la función
 *  malloc para un nodo y lo inicializa si y solo si la memoria es asignada.
 *  Si ocurre un error en la asignación de memoria se provoca la finalización
 *  del programa.
 */
hashTable *crearTabla() {
    hashTable *nueva = (hashTable *) malloc(TABLAHASH);
    if (nueva == NULL) {
        printf("No hay memoria suficiente para continuar.\n");
        printf("El programa terminará\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        (*nueva).cuerpo[i] = crearLista();
        (*nueva).elementos += (*nueva).cuerpo[i]->longitud;
    }
    if ((*nueva).elementos != 0) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return nueva;
}

/*  La función hash recibe un string apuntado por string y calcula su valor hash
 *  como se sigue:
 *      hash(string) = ValorASCII(LOWERCASE(string[0])) % ValorASCII('a')
 */
int hash(char *string) {
    return tolower(string[0]) % 'a';
}

/*  La función agregar recibe una tablaHash apuntada por tabla y un string,
 *  apuntado por nombre y agrega en la posición hash(nombre)-ésima del cuerpo de
 *  tabla un nodo cuyo nombre es nombre. Y se incrementa elementos de tabla en
 *  uno.
 */
void agregar(hashTable *tabla, char *nombre) {
    int indice = hash(nombre);
    node *nuevo = crearNodo();
    (*nuevo).nombre = strcpy((*nuevo).nombre, nombre);
    agregarElemento((*tabla).cuerpo[indice], nuevo);
    (*tabla).elementos++;
}

/*  La función buscar recibe una tablaHash apuntada por tabla y un string,
 *  apuntado por nombre y busca en la posición hash(nombre)-ésima del cuerpo de
 *  tabla un nodo cuyo nombre es nombre. Si el nodo es encontrado se retorna su
 *  nombre, si no, se retorna el string vacío.
 */
char *buscar(hashTable *tabla, char *nombre) {
    node *elemento = buscarElemento((*tabla).cuerpo[hash(nombre)], nombre);
    if (elemento != NULL) {
        return (*elemento).nombre;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/*  La función eliminar recibe una tablaHash apuntada por tabla y un string,
 *  apuntado por nombre y elimina en la posición hash(nombre)-ésima del cuerpo
 *  de tabla un nodo cuyo nombre es nombre. Si el nodo es encontrado se retorna 
 *  su nombre y se decrementa en uno elementos en tabla, si no, se retorna el
 *  string vacío.
 */
char *eliminar(hashTable *tabla, char *nombre) {
    node *elemento = borrarElemento((*tabla).cuerpo[hash(nombre)], nombre);
    if (elemento != NULL) {
        (*tabla).elementos--;
        return (*elemento).nombre;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/*  La función imprimirTabla recibe una tablaHash apuntada por tabla y muestra
 *  por la salida estándar los nombres de los elementos de la tabla separados
 *  por saltos de línea si y sólo si elementos en tabla es mayor que cero.
 */
void imprimirTabla(hashTable *tabla) {
    if ((*tabla).elementos > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        char inicioMayus = 'A';
        char inicioMinus = 'a';
        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            printf("Empiezan en %c/%c: ", inicioMayus, inicioMinus);
            imprimirLista((*tabla).cuerpo[i]);
            inicioMayus++;
            inicioMinus++;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que hay veces que sí logra imprimir la tabla de Hash correctamente, pero otras arroja violación de segmento, y es el mismo código compilado.

Comment: ¿Y en ambos casos trabaja con los mismos datos de entrada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La violación de segmento ocurre cuando un programa trata de acceder un área de memoria no permitida, es muy común que esto ocurra por un mal manejo de apuntadores, por ejemplo en el método crearTabla inicializas la memoria para un struct hashTable

```
hashTable *nueva = (hashTable *) malloc(TABLAHASH);
```

Esta estructura tiene a su interior una variable entera que no has inicializado en el cuerpo del método crearTabla, esto de entrada causa problemas.

```
struct tablaHash {
    list *cuerpo[26];
    int elementos;
};
```

La función **malloc** solo hace una asignación de un espacio de memoria de acuerdo al tamaño suministrado, esto no quiere decir que la función inicialice los valores o campos de la estructura que vas a alojar en dicho espacio de memoria, de hecho la instrucción **malloc** ni si quiera recibe la estructura para el cual se va a reservar la memoria, solo recibe el tamaño y tampoco hace una limpieza de esa área de memoria. Por lo anterior es necesario que el campo **elementos** se iguale a cero (0) para que tenga un valor adecuado, de otro modo puede tomar el valor que se encuentre en esa area de memoria que podría ser cualquier numero.

Otro detalle importante es que los tamaño de un objeto se debe calcular de forma correcta, en tu código se encuentra declarado lo siguiente:

```
#define NODO sizeof(node *)
#define LISTA sizeof(list *)
#define TABLAHASH sizeof(hashTable *)
```

Y con estas macros estas haciendo la invocación de la función **malloc** pero resulta que la definición está errada, esto NO está calculando el tamaño de las estructuras, está calculando el tamaño de un apuntador el cual siempre sin importar de que estructura hablemos tendrá un tamaño reducido (de 8 bytes si mal no lo recuerdo), la forma correcta seria que lo cambies dejándolo así:

```
#define NODO sizeof(node)
#define LISTA sizeof(list)
#define TABLAHASH sizeof(hashTable)
```

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior y ajustando tu programa ya no deberías tener este problema en el cual algunas veces el programa funciona y en otras no.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ese pequeño detalle no lo había notado. Fuiste de increíble ayuda.